# Firefox addon sdk persist cookie from angular

Tags: angularjs, firefox-addon

I am altering the Firefox new tab page and want my angularjs webpage to be able to persist its $cookies. Unfortunately this seems to be disabled, as they are deleted on reload. Is there a way to access/save cookies from angular?

Comment: This is a good question, I've using a lot of angular in my firefox addon gui's lately. I think your situation is that you are using cookie from the new tab scope, which is privelaged scope. Did you check the cookies via "Options" tab cookies section? Did you see the cookie? And it was cleared on reload of that tab? Did you try setting cookies in the classic js way? Of course the privelaged methods will work but we want to get angular working. So lets do some troubleshooting togather.

Comment: Yeah I did not want to fall back to privileged methods either. I found localstorage to persist and fell back to localstorage instead of $cookies.

Comment: The thing though, the about:newtab page is privelaged itself. Can you share your code on github I'm really interested in seeing it.

Comment: Oh sorry for not being clear. I use privileged access to the tab in my index.js, but stayed clear of it in my angular app to make it browser agnostic.

Comment: Are you just re-loading the tab, or are you re-running Firefox using the SDK's `cfx`?  If you are using `cfx`, then there are a few questions/answers that explain that `cfx` uses a new profile each time you run it and thus changes are not persistent form one run to the next.

Comment: I was reloading the tab